# Resellerclub API works in test but not working in LIVE

Tags: web-services

I am using [Resellerclub API](http://manage.resellerclub.com/kb/answer/753) to Create a Customer and register the DOMAIN. Its working fine with the test environment:

```
https://test.httpapi.com/
```

But the same thing fails when using in LIVE:

```
https://httpapi.com/
```

Below is the request i am using for creating a customer to book a domain:

Test(which works fine):

```
https://test.httpapi.com/api/customers/signup.xml?auth-userid=xxxxx&auth-password=xxxxxx&username=prasadvemala@xxxx.com&passwd=xxxxxx&name=Prasad Vemala&company=Prasad Vemala&address-line-1=my address1&city=Fort Collins&state=CO&country=US&zipcode=80526&phone-cc=1&phone=1234567890&lang-pref=en
```

But in LIVE(fails):

```
 https://httpapi.com/api/customers/signup.xml?auth-userid=xxxxx&auth-password=xxxxxx&username=prasadvemala@xxxx.com&passwd=xxxxxx&name=Prasad Vemala&company=Prasad Vemala&address-line-1=my address1&city=Fort Collins&state=CO&country=US&zipcode=80526&phone-cc=1&phone=1234567890&lang-pref=en
```

Below is the error i got in the LIVE environment:

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Does anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The test api environment allows GET calls while for some functions you have to use POST when using the live API.

Adding a customer requieres always the POST Method.

http://manage.resellerclub.com/kb/answer/804

Regards,
Marco

Answer (score 0):

Even the live call contains the same URL including 'test' and it will work